# How can I differentiate between $1 as a shell variable and $1 as an awk variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line

When I pass the Command Line arguments to my script, We have to access that value by using $1, $2 etc., Similarly, when we are using awk, we can mention the columns of a file as $1,$2 etc.,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cat $1 | awk '$1 > 20'
```

- Let us assume I have passed a file name as a command line argument, and we can refer that argument by using $1.
- Let us assume the file content is as follows.

  ```
   20 A         
   10 B   
   5  D  
   13 K
   50 C
  ```

**How can I tell, when reading this code, whether it will access the command line `$1` -- the input file name -- or the first column of the output from `cat`?**

Comment: Provide more details of your problem

Comment: @anubhava, Yeah, Sure

Comment: @NagaVenkateshGavini Are you going to clarify the question?

Comment: They are two different `$1`, one a shell positional argument number 1 and the other `$1` is AWK first field.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano yeah, they are different, But how can I differentiate while I was writing the script and using awk in that same script.

Comment: I've edited the question's title to better reflect the question as clarified in your above comment.

Comment: BTW, `cat $1` is generally buggy. It won't work with a file named `my inputs.txt`, for example, or a file named `-inputs.txt` unless its name is preceded with `./` or other elements. If you *must* use `cat`, use it as `cat -- "$1"` -- but it's better to just pass the filename straight to `awk`, or to use `<"$1"` to perform a shell redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy rule here: **The shell does not perform any expansions on single-quoted strings.**

This is true in other scenarios as well: `echo '$1'` prints the exact string `$1`.

Thus, in the following code (edited for correctness -- lack of double quotes around the shell variable caused a bug, and use of `cat` had needless inefficiency):

```
awk '$1 > 20' <"$1"
```

...we have `$1 > 20` treated as literal by the shell and parsed as code only by `awk`, and `"$1"` -- being in double quotes, expanded by the shell.

Comment: So if the first argument to the script is "myfile.txt", this runs the awk script `$1 > 20`with input from myfile.txt. Conversely, if you swap the double- and single-quotes to `awk "$1 > 20" <'$1'`, it would run the awk script `myfile.txt > 20` (which doesn't make any sense), and try to read input from a file literally named "$1" (which doesn't make much sense either). Basically, it's all determined by how things are quoted.

Comment: @charles Duffy, Now If I want to take 20 as the Second command line Argument, Now I have to make my code as this [awk '$1 > "$2" ' < "$1"], But the code is displaying entire Data. Any Help !!

Comment: That's almost certainly incorrect quoting, but we can't guess what you are actually trying to say. Perhaps something like `awk -v limit="$2" '$1 > limit' <"$1"` (though really the redirection is superfluous here; like most file-oriented commands, Awk accepts a list of input files to read).

Comment: @NagaVenkateshGavini, if that's your problem, there's a separate question for it: [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is any another way to represent the columns while using awk
>   in the shell script?

You can represent them using variables For example

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i}}' file
```

Here `NF` is the total number of fields(which may be considered as columns.) As `i` gets different values in loop the `$i` would expand to individual columns like `$1`, `$2` and so.